# I have a confusion related this python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super, self

The following Python code shows:

```
i from B is :  24660
```

I think that it should show `i from B is :  28770` as the `__init__` method is being called from the parent class using `super()` and it should run the method `calc_i()` form the parent class, not the child class.

Python Code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.calc_i(411)
        
    def calc_i(self,i):
        self.i = 70 * i
        
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("i from B is : " , self.i)
        
    def calc_i(self,i):
        self.i = 60 * i
        
b = B()
```

Edit: I'm trying to ask what is the reason that python is running the `calc_i()` method from the child class and not parent class. Even though, `super().__init__()` is called from the child class.

Comment: *"It should run the method form the parent class."* Nope.

Comment: No it shouldn’t.  b’s `self` is an instance of `B`

Comment: Reason? That's what I'm trying to ask!

Comment: "it should run the method `calc_i()` form the parent class, not the child class" - as you can see in your example code, Python thinks otherwise, so what's the question?

Comment: ‘Reason?` - if that’s what you want to ask then put this into your question.

Comment: A `B`-type object knows how to `.calc_i`, when asked to do so, no matter what routine is running.

Comment: @someone, have you tried to search for the answer in [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)?

Comment: If `A` should always init with the `A` version of `calc_i()`, then tell it so. Rather than `self.calc_i(411)` call `A.calc_i(self, 411)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a property of polymorphism. Here, class B is the child class which inherits from class A. When you make the super call back to class A, it calls `calc_i(self, i)`, but `calc_i(self,i)` has been overwritten by the definition in class B, hence it gives 24660.

That's just how polymorphism works in many programming languages; you'll see questions pertaining to this on AP Computer Science exams.